# Преобразовать массив в массив для меню

Tags: php, массивы, динамические-массивы

есть массив данных полученных по Rest API
Пытаюсь из этих данных сделать меню, но для этого нужно его преобразовать с учетом вложенности (думаю это делается циклом)

Перерыл интернет, везде рекурсия с обычными числовыми id, а у меня id это строка, сам пробовал делать через foreach, получилось это

```
 foreach ($elements as $item){

     $thisRef = &$ref[$item['objectId']];

     $thisRef['parent'] = &$item['parent'];
     $thisRef['name'] = $item['property']['ru']['value'];
     $thisRef['objectId'] = $item['objectId'];
     $thisRef['number'] = $item['number'];
   $thisRef['duration'] = $item['duration'];
     $thisRef['object'] = $item['object'];
     $thisRef['listorder'] = $item['listorder'];

    if($item['parent'] == 0) {
         $items[$item['objectId']] = &$thisRef;
    } else {

    $ref[$item['parent']]['child'][$item['objectId']] = &$thisRef;       



    }


  }



 print_r($items);
```

Написанный мною цикл работает плохо, он выводит ветку только до 2 уровня

массив $elements выкладываю ниже в print_r и var_export

[objectId] - это id элемента

[parent]  - это родитель элемента, он ссылается на objectId родителя, если он пустой или равен 0 значит у него нет родителя

Большая просьба предложить решение с неограниченной вложенностью.

Желаю добра тому кто мне поможет.

Массив через print_r

```
   Array
    (
     [0] => Array
         (
             [parent] => D0384DBB-F67C-FE92-FF46-F192B3F83B00
             [created] => 1540568545112
             [element_id] => 
             [ownerId] => 
             [type] => 
             [duration] => 
             [number] => 1
             [start_time] => 
             [enable] => 
             [tiam] => 
             [listorder] => 1
             [quest_id] => E18A9589-6AB2-8304-FFFC-98C11314CD00
             [updated] => 1540569546246
             [value] => 
             [objectId] => 0DE56A96-9FA9-64E0-FFAB-97A246517200
             [object] => round
             [___class] => Elements
             [property] => Array
                 (
                     [ru] => Array
                         (
                             [language_code] => ru
                             [created] => 1540568545865
                             [lang_id] => 0E5BD427-7883-903C-FFDD-2309E2D79800
                             [element_id] => 0DE56A96-9FA9-64E0-FFAB-97A246517200
                             [quest_id] => E18A9589-6AB2-8304-FFFC-98C11314CD00
                             [type] => 
                             [ownerId] => 
                             [value] => Раунд
                             [updated] => 
                             [objectId] => C28EE86F-71BC-A6D3-FFF6-707638303500
                             [object] => round
                             [___class] => Elements_values
                         )

                 )

         )

     [1] => Array
         (
             [parent] => 
             [created] => 1540540322673
             [element_id] => 
             [ownerId] => 
             [type] => 
             [duration] => 
             [number] => 1
             [start_time] => 
             [enable] => 
             [tiam] => 
             [listorder] => 1
             [quest_id] => E18A9589-6AB2-8304-FFFC-98C11314CD00
             [updated] => 1540564573693
             [value] => 
             [objectId] => 4449513D-1CDD-00EA-FFDF-1947E4FDEA00
             [object] => team
             [___class] => Elements
             [property] => Array
                 (
                     [ru] => Array
                         (
                             [language_code] => ru
                             [created] => 1540540323417
                             [lang_id] => 0E5BD427-7883-903C-FFDD-2309E2D79800
                             [element_id] => 4449513D-1CDD-00EA-FFDF-1947E4FDEA00
                             [quest_id] => E18A9589-6AB2-8304-FFFC-98C11314CD00
                             [type] => 
                             [ownerId] => 
                             [value] => Команда
                             [updated] => 
                             [objectId] => 2B2C86CF-E1F8-5D2C-FF0E-1DB592CC7500
                             [object] => team
                             [___class] => Elements_values
                         )

                 )

         )

     [2] => Array
         (
             [parent] => F0BFCFFA-D8F7-B5BE-FF37-D92AE35BBD00
             [created] => 1540567572958
             [element_id] => 
             [ownerId] => 
             [type] => 
             [duration] => 
             [number] => 1
             [start_time] => 
             [enable] => 
             [tiam] => 
             [listorder] => 1
             [quest_id] => E18A9589-6AB2-8304-FFFC-98C11314CD00
             [updated] => 1540567674259
             [value] => 
             [objectId] => D0384DBB-F67C-FE92-FF46-F192B3F83B00
             [object] => stage
             [___class] => Elements
             [property] => Array
                 (
                     [ru] => Array
                         (
                             [language_code] => ru
                             [created] => 1540567573722
                             [lang_id] => 0E5BD427-7883-903C-FFDD-2309E2D79800
                             [element_id] => D0384DBB-F67C-FE92-FF46-F192B3F83B00
                             [quest_id] => E18A9589-6AB2-8304-FFFC-98C11314CD00
                             [type] => 
                             [ownerId] => 
                             [value] => Этап
                             [updated] => 
                             [objectId] => 4E694471-70B3-C12B-FF79-97895532DD00
                             [object] => stage
                             [___class] => Elements_values
                         )

                 )

         )

     [3] => Array
         (
             [parent] => 4449513D-1CDD-00EA-FFDF-1947E4FDEA00
             [created] => 1540565297592
             [element_id] => 
             [ownerId] => 
             [type] => 
             [duration] => 
             [number] => 1
             [start_time] => 
             [enable] => 
             [tiam] => 
             [listorder] => 1
             [quest_id] => E18A9589-6AB2-8304-FFFC-98C11314CD00
             [updated] => 1540565310503
             [value] => 
             [objectId] => F0BFCFFA-D8F7-B5BE-FF37-D92AE35BBD00
             [object] => route
             [___class] => Elements
             [property] => Array
                 (
                     [ru] => Array
                         (
                             [language_code] => ru
                             [created] => 1540565298342
                             [lang_id] => 0E5BD427-7883-903C-FFDD-2309E2D79800
                             [element_id] => F0BFCFFA-D8F7-B5BE-FF37-D92AE35BBD00
                             [quest_id] => E18A9589-6AB2-8304-FFFC-98C11314CD00
                             [type] => 
                             [ownerId] => 
                             [value] => Маршрут
                             [updated] => 
                             [objectId] => 9CD62B6E-EACF-2911-FF57-3FF369F2BE00
                             [object] => route
                             [___class] => Elements_values
                         )

                 )

         )

   )
```

Массив через var_export

```
array (
    0 => 
   array (
     'parent' => 'D0384DBB-F67C-FE92-FF46-F192B3F83B00',
     'created' => 1540568545112,
     'element_id' => NULL,
     'ownerId' => NULL,
     'type' => NULL,
     'duration' => NULL,
     'number' => '1',
     'start_time' => NULL,
     'enable' => NULL,
     'tiam' => NULL,
     'listorder' => '1',
     'quest_id' => 'E18A9589-6AB2-8304-FFFC-98C11314CD00',
     'updated' => 1540569546246,
     'value' => NULL,
     'objectId' => '0DE56A96-9FA9-64E0-FFAB-97A246517200',
     'object' => 'round',
     '___class' => 'Elements',
     'property' => 
     array (
       'ru' => 
       array (
         'language_code' => 'ru',
         'created' => 1540568545865,
         'lang_id' => '0E5BD427-7883-903C-FFDD-2309E2D79800',
         'element_id' => '0DE56A96-9FA9-64E0-FFAB-97A246517200',
         'quest_id' => 'E18A9589-6AB2-8304-FFFC-98C11314CD00',
         'type' => NULL,
         'ownerId' => NULL,
         'value' => 'Раунд',
         'updated' => NULL,
         'objectId' => 'C28EE86F-71BC-A6D3-FFF6-707638303500',
         'object' => 'round',
         '___class' => 'Elements_values',
       ),
     ),
   ),
   1 => 
   array (
     'parent' => NULL,
     'created' => 1540540322673,
     'element_id' => NULL,
     'ownerId' => NULL,
     'type' => NULL,
     'duration' => NULL,
     'number' => '1',
     'start_time' => NULL,
     'enable' => NULL,
     'tiam' => NULL,
     'listorder' => '1',
     'quest_id' => 'E18A9589-6AB2-8304-FFFC-98C11314CD00',
     'updated' => 1540564573693,
     'value' => NULL,
     'objectId' => '4449513D-1CDD-00EA-FFDF-1947E4FDEA00',
     'object' => 'team',
     '___class' => 'Elements',
     'property' => 
     array (
       'ru' => 
       array (
         'language_code' => 'ru',
         'created' => 1540540323417,
         'lang_id' => '0E5BD427-7883-903C-FFDD-2309E2D79800',
         'element_id' => '4449513D-1CDD-00EA-FFDF-1947E4FDEA00',
         'quest_id' => 'E18A9589-6AB2-8304-FFFC-98C11314CD00',
         'type' => NULL,
         'ownerId' => NULL,
         'value' => 'Команда',
         'updated' => NULL,
         'objectId' => '2B2C86CF-E1F8-5D2C-FF0E-1DB592CC7500',
         'object' => 'team',
         '___class' => 'Elements_values',
       ),
     ),
   ),
   2 => 
   array (
     'parent' => 'F0BFCFFA-D8F7-B5BE-FF37-D92AE35BBD00',
     'created' => 1540567572958,
     'element_id' => NULL,
     'ownerId' => NULL,
     'type' => NULL,
     'duration' => NULL,
     'number' => '1',
     'start_time' => NULL,
     'enable' => NULL,
     'tiam' => NULL,
     'listorder' => '1',
     'quest_id' => 'E18A9589-6AB2-8304-FFFC-98C11314CD00',
     'updated' => 1540567674259,
     'value' => NULL,
     'objectId' => 'D0384DBB-F67C-FE92-FF46-F192B3F83B00',
     'object' => 'stage',
     '___class' => 'Elements',
     'property' => 
     array (
       'ru' => 
       array (
         'language_code' => 'ru',
         'created' => 1540567573722,
         'lang_id' => '0E5BD427-7883-903C-FFDD-2309E2D79800',
         'element_id' => 'D0384DBB-F67C-FE92-FF46-F192B3F83B00',
         'quest_id' => 'E18A9589-6AB2-8304-FFFC-98C11314CD00',
         'type' => NULL,
         'ownerId' => NULL,
         'value' => 'Этап',
         'updated' => NULL,
         'objectId' => '4E694471-70B3-C12B-FF79-97895532DD00',
         'object' => 'stage',
         '___class' => 'Elements_values',
       ),
     ),
   ),
   3 => 
   array (
     'parent' => '4449513D-1CDD-00EA-FFDF-1947E4FDEA00',
     'created' => 1540565297592,
     'element_id' => NULL,
     'ownerId' => NULL,
     'type' => NULL,
     'duration' => NULL,
     'number' => '1',
     'start_time' => NULL,
     'enable' => NULL,
     'tiam' => NULL,
     'listorder' => '1',
     'quest_id' => 'E18A9589-6AB2-8304-FFFC-98C11314CD00',
     'updated' => 1540565310503,
     'value' => NULL,
     'objectId' => 'F0BFCFFA-D8F7-B5BE-FF37-D92AE35BBD00',
     'object' => 'route',
     '___class' => 'Elements',
     'property' => 
     array (
       'ru' => 
       array (
         'language_code' => 'ru',
         'created' => 1540565298342,
         'lang_id' => '0E5BD427-7883-903C-FFDD-2309E2D79800',
         'element_id' => 'F0BFCFFA-D8F7-B5BE-FF37-D92AE35BBD00',
         'quest_id' => 'E18A9589-6AB2-8304-FFFC-98C11314CD00',
         'type' => NULL,
         'ownerId' => NULL,
         'value' => 'Маршрут',
         'updated' => NULL,
         'objectId' => '9CD62B6E-EACF-2911-FF57-3FF369F2BE00',
         'object' => 'route',
         '___class' => 'Elements_values',
       ),
     ),
   ),
 )
```

На выходе мне нужно примерно такое:

Array
     (

```
 ......

     [4449513D-1CDD-00EA-FFDF-1947E4FDEA00] => Array
         (
             [parent] => 
             [name] => Команда
             [objectId] => 4449513D-1CDD-00EA-FFDF-1947E4FDEA00
             [number] => 1
             [duration] => 
             [object] => team
             [listorder] => 1
             [child] => Array
                 (
                     [F0BFCFFA-D8F7-B5BE-FF37-D92AE35BBD00] => Array
                         (
                             [parent] => 4449513D-1CDD-00EA-FFDF-1947E4FDEA00
                             [name] => Маршрут
                             [objectId] => F0BFCFFA-D8F7-B5BE-FF37-D92AE35BBD00
                             [number] => 1
                             [duration] => 
                             [object] => route
                             [listorder] => 1
                             [child]=> Array

                                            (
                                                [D0384DBB-F67C-FE92-FF46-F192B3F83B00] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [parent] => F0BFCFFA-D8F7-B5BE-FF37-D92AE35BBD00
                                                        [name] => Этап
                                                        [objectId] => D0384DBB-F67C-FE92-FF46-F192B3F83B00
                                                        [number] => 1
                                                        [duration] => 
                                                        [object] => stage
                                                        [listorder] => 1
                                                    )



                             )


                         )

                 )

 ....

         )



 )
```

Comment: ну используйте строковой `id` это как бы не проблема

Comment: смотрите мой цикл, я пробовал делать, но вывод с ограничением до 2 уровня только

Comment: рекурсию используйте т.е. в нутри если есть parent то снова функцию запускать

Comment: "Желаю добра тому кто мне поможет." +1

Comment: Видимо мои познания в php все же слабоваты, надеюсь кто-нибудь сможет мне помочь..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно ли я понимаю, что проблема в связях parent_id? Нужно обойти массив, и по нему выстроить многоуровневое вложенное меню, через parent_id

Да, классический вариант тут рекурсия. Но проблема в том, что глубина стека в php как правило установлена в 512 элементов, т.е. это максимальный уровень вложенности рекурсии, при дефолтных настройках.

В любом случае настройки тут менять не вариант, т.к. теоретически глубина вложенности не ограничена, и может быть и миллион, и миллиард, и больше - никакой памяти не хватит.

Но программирование штука сугубо прикладная, и многие такие моменты в программировании обходятся не теоретически, а элементарными физическими ограничениями (как правило ограничениями железа) и здравым смыслом: для меню 512 уровней - это с головой, на практике меню как правило двухуровневое, редко трех, больше уже экзотика. 10 уровней наверное вообще нигде не встречается, т.к. такое меню уже элементарно неудобно - попробуйте полазить по такому, с ума сойдете.

Так что разумный ответ такой: пользуйтесь рекурсией, и не заморачивайтесь. Текстовые идентификаторы никак не помешают выстроить иерархию - даже html-код в качестве ключей можно использовать, это симметричный массив, ему все равно.

Можно обойтись и без рекурсии конечно, воспользовавшись do...while циклом, но это будет очень дорого стоить, для массива из тысячи элементов потребуется перебрать два миллиона элементов, для массива из миллиона элементов потребуется перебрать два триллиона элементов, плюс код получится очень запутанным.

Для меню такой велосипед изобретать явно не стоит.

Пример рекурсии https://repl.it/@tomasj/recirsionmenu

Comment: Спасибо за подробный комментарий, не смог сделать даже рекурсией, помогите, у меня в меню будет в будущем не более 20 элементов, речь о миллионе не идет

Прошу Вас помочь, как правильно написать методом рекурсии?

Comment: добавил вид массива который мне нужен на выходе

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что проблема в связях parent_id? Нужно обойти массив, и по нему выстроить многоуровневое вложенное меню, через parent_id
-----------------
Да Вы правильно поняли, связь идет по parent

Comment: Например так https://repl.it/@tomasj/recirsionmenu

Comment: спасибо! предложите решение, оно верное!

Comment: Если это значит добавить инфу в ответ - добавил